# How to Stop JTree from collapsing after removing a node from the tree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel

I'm making a JTree and I have a button that removes a node from the tree. Everytime I removde the node with the button, the Tree automatically collapse. I've read that it's becasue I'm using `.reload()`. I've also read some SO answers that suggested using `.nodeChanged(node)`, which I've tried but when I use that, I believe the model is getting updated, but the tree doesn't reload accordingly in the GUI. How can I get the tree not to collapse?

Here's a simple SSCCE with the default JTree and a button to remove a node

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class StopTreeCollapse extends JApplet {

    JTree tree = new JTree();
    JButton jbtRemove = new JButton("Remove Node");

    public StopTreeCollapse(){

        add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(jbtRemove, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jbtRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();

                if (paths == null) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "No node in the tree is selected");
                    return;
                }
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = null; 
                for (TreePath path : paths) {
                    node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (path.getLastPathComponent());
                    if (node.isRoot()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot remove the root");
                    } else {
                        node.removeFromParent();
                    }
                }
                ((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel()).reload();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reload()` essentially says "the whole tree may have changed, forget anything you previously knew about it and start again".

Instead of using `node.removeFromParent()` and then reloading the whole tree, try

```
((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel()).removeNodeFromParent(node);
```

This will fire a more specific modification event telling listeners that that particular node has been removed but the rest of the tree is unchanged, so you no longer require the `reload()` call.

Comment: `((DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel()).removeNodeFromParent(node);` is still collapsing the entire tree for me, and I've never been calling `reload()` simply `updateUI()`